# Check size of node js stream using socket.io-stream

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nodejs-stream

I'm using socket.io-stream to upload a file, I want to know the size of data upload to limit.

This is my server code:

```
ss       = require('socket.io-stream'),
SocketIo = require('socket.io'),
path     = require('path'),
fs       = require('fs');

let io      = SocketIo.listen(server);

io.of("/users").on('connection',function(socket){
    ss(socket).on('avatar-upload', function(stream, data) {
        let filename = path.format({
            root: '/',
            dir: '/home/user/project/public/upload/',
            base: data.name
        });
    });
    // Check data stream size to limit here
})
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you will get some idea to limit on stream size

```
  var blobStream = ss.createBlobReadStream(file);
    var size = 0;

    blobStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
      size += chunk.length;
      console.log(Math.floor(size / file.size * 100) + '%');
      // -> e.g. '42%' 
    });

    blobStream.pipe(stream);
```